# Set assignee field when creating an issue in JIRA via Python suds

Tags: python, soap, jira, suds

Using JIRA version 4.2. With Python 2.7 and suds 0.4, how can I create an issue with assignee field set? The assignee field gets ignored in the code below.

```
new_issue = client.service.createIssue(auth, {
            'project': 'NAHLP',
            # issue_type = Incident Report.
            'type': '11',
            'assignee': 'assignee_username',
            'priority': '2',
            'summary': 'summary',
            'description': 'description',
            'customFieldValues': [
                # Reporter Location = NA.
                {'customfieldId':'customfield_10019', 'values':['10011']},
                ]
            })
```

I know that you can update the issue with an assignee (see my answer) but I want to assign the issue when creating it.  Is this possible?

Note:  All our usernames are the users' email addresses and contain '@' and '.' symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Dave, again, for this answer.

The soap API won't set fields that aren't visible on the Jira UI's screen at the relevant point of the workflow. The "create issue" screen is considered the relevant screen when you call the createIssue method, but the assignee field isn't visible on the 'create issue' screen.

You could either do your createissue call without the assignee, then follow it with an updateissue call to set assignee.  Alternatively, we could add the assignee field in the initial create issue workflow.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Dave for this alternative of updating the issue with an assignee.  Note, this does not answer the question of how to assign a ticket when creating an issue.

I need to be passing an array as the value of the assignee field even though it only allows one value.  (The same applies to any field you want to update with the updateIssue call).  So, instead of:

```
client.service.updateIssue(auth, 'NAHLP-38630', {'assignee': 'qgir@ogilvy.com',})
```

do this:

```
client.service.updateIssue(auth,'NAHLP-38630',[ {'id' : 'assignee', 'values' : ['qgir@ogilvy.com']}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create an issue and set the assignee. Make sure you're using the user name, not the full name or email address. Check the atlassian-jira.log for errors. Check the assignee is not hidden on the create screen for that issue type in that project. The JIRA Python CLI has a createissues action that should do exactly this with suds.

~Matt

Comment: Matt, I am using the username.  Would it matter if the username contains special characters?  The reason why I am asking is that all our usernames are the users' email addresses and contain '.' and '@' symbols.

Comment: I created a user that does not have special characters, and it made no difference.  Still have to check logs.  Is there a way to check the logs from the web interface?

Comment: Using the JIRA Python CLI still does not allow for setting the assignee when creating an issue.  Is there a project setting in JIRA that disallows this?

Comment: I just tested the CLI with this: python ./jira -s http://localhost:8080 create -p TEST -s "New issue from CLI 2" -d "Empty empty" -a devtest       and it worked fine. Check that the user can have issues assigned to them?

Comment: Thanks Matt.  The problem was that the assignee field was removed from the createIssue workflow, and only available after an issue had been created.  Hence I was not able to set a field that did not exist!  It would be more helpful in the future if JIRA would respond to such a SOAP call with a warning ("Warning: field 'assignee' not available").

Answer (score 0):

**pass the assignee as the dictionary with key as name, As shown in given example below**

```
issue_data = {   
    'project' : {'key':'project_id'},
    'summary' : 'Issue Creation using Automation Scription',
    'description' : 'Setting the description string',
    'issuetype' : {'name':'Bug'},
    'labels' : ['jiraAutomation','label'],
    'assignee': {'name':'jira_user_id'}
}

new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_data)
print(new_issue.key)
```