# Assigning a jira issue while its creation in a python script

Tags: python-3.x, jira, python-jira

I am working on a program that creates a bunch of jira issues with the following function style:

```
def issue_create():
        url = "jira_url"
        username = auth_name
        password = auth_pwd
        jira_inst = jira.JIRA(url, basic_auth=(username, password))

        test = {
            "project":          {"key": "123"},
            "issuetype":        {"name": "Task"},

            "summary":          'title',
            "description":      'description' ,
            "duedate":          'due_date'

            "timetracking":    {"originalEstimate": "1d"},
        }
        created = jira_inst.create_issues([test])

issue_create()
```

This works perfectly well for the creation of all my issues (around 15 of them) but i have tried many ways of assigning these issues to different people and even assigning them all to 1 person on my jira but no matter what it give me various error messages the most frequent of which is:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/api/latest/issue /[%7B'status':%20'Error',%20'error':%20%7B'duedate':%20'Error%20parsing%20date%20string:%20'%7D,%20'issue':%20None,%20'input_fields':%20%7B'project':%20%7B'key':%20'SAM'%7D,%20'issuetype':%20%7B'name':%20'Task'%7D,%20'summary':%20'Badges%20pour%20%20%20(Stagiaire%20)',%20'description':%20'Faire%20restituer%20le%20badge%20immeuble%20et%20parking%20de%20%20%20qui%20part%20le%20()',%20'duedate':%20'',%20'timetracking':%20%7B'originalEstimate':%20'1d'%7D%7D%7D]/assignee
```

Any ideas on how to fix this and assign these issues?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Its difficult to decrypt error message from this code, can you post the error message in better format?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/rest/api/latest/issue /[%7B'status':%20'Error',%20'error':%20%7B'duedate':%20'Error%20parsing%20date%20string:%20'%7D,%20'issue':%20None,%20'input_fields':%20%7B'project':%20%7B'key':%20'SAM'%7D,%20'issuetype':%20%7B'name':%20'Task'%7D,%20'summary':%20'Badges%20pour%20%20%20(Stagiaire%20)',%20'description':%20'Faire%20restituer%20le%20badge%20immeuble%20et%20parking%20de%20%20%20qui%20part%20le%20()',%20'duedate':%20'',%20'timetracking':%20%7B'originalEstimate':%20'1d'%7D%7D%7D]/assignee

Comment: Are you trying to assign them on creation or after creation?

Comment: either really, they just need to be assigned to people once the program has ended

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using direct assignee in JIRA is that it's not directly possible if GDPR strict mode is used in JIRA Cloud. However, there are two alternatives.

Alternative 1

a. Create the JIRA ticket without assignee and store the JIRA Ticket ID

b. Get the UserID by querying for a username `/rest/api/2/user/assignable/search?issueKey=SCRUM-37&query=yahandy`

c. Use the JIRA Ticket ID and UserID from above api as below

```
curl --request PUT \
> --url 'https://[myCloudSite].atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/SCRUM-37' \
> --header 'Authorization: Basic [username+tokenEncodedStringHere]' \
> --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
> --data '{"fields":{"assignee": {"accountId":"123456:44448ae7-90ce-4e62-bfda-e88abcde5555"}}}'
```

Reference: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Assignee-set-to-unassigned-while-creating-ticket-through-the/qaq-p/1310631

Alternative 2

An easier way to do this would be to use Project Automation tool provided by JIRA. There are several conditions based on which ticket assignment can be rotated to different people. This way you don't have to deal with the atomicity problem of three different REST API calls and also offload the work to JIRA.

Reference: https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/automation-template-library/auto-assign

Answer (score 0):

Try to use such fields as `data` for your request:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "project": {
      "key": "TIOHM"
    }, 
    "summary": "Testing Jira REST API with CURL", 
    "description": "test 123", 
    "issuetype": {
      "name": "Task"
    }, 
    "assignee": {
      "name": "a.fomina"
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is the doc](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/) with **more examples**.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicates [Set assignee field when creating an issue in JIRA via Python suds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944627/set-assignee-field-when-creating-an-issue-in-jira-via-python-suds). In summary can't be done at creation time.

Answer (score 0):

To assign user to tickets use the Jira accountId.

Use this API or code to fetch the account_id by **email address**:

**Using `atlassian-python-api`:**

This code will return accounts array according to your query, loop on it to get the `account['accountId']`

```
def getAccountsByEmail(self, email):
    logger.info("Getting accounts for email: " + email)
    try:
        return self.jira.user_find_by_user_string(query=email)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
```

The accountId should look like this: `"712020:5ce38bb7-xxxx-41e6-xxxx-b3c7c45502a9"`

**Using REST API:**

Sample request:

https://myorg.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/user/search?query=naor.bar@xxx.com

Sample result:

```
{
    ...
    "accountId": "712020:5ce38bb7-xxxx-41e6-xxxx-b3c7c45502a9",
    "accountType": "atlassian",
    "emailAddress": "naor.bar@xxx.com",
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now, use the accountId in your Python code; e.g.

```
def createIssue(self):
    logger.info("Creating a new Jira issue...")
    try:
        return self.jira.create_issue(fields={
            "project": {
                "key": "MY-PROJ"
            },
            "summary": "Test with JIRA python API",
            "description": "Test with JIRA python API",
            "issuetype": {
                "name": "Task"
            },
            "assignee": {
                "accountId": "712020:5ce38bb7-xxxx-41e6-xxxx-b3c7c45502a9"
            }
        })
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e.response.text)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an assignee to your test dictionary. e.g.:

```
test = {
        "project":          {"key": "123"},
        "issuetype":        {"name": "Task"},

        "summary":          'title',
        "description":      'description' ,
        "duedate":          'due_date'

        "timetracking":    {"originalEstimate": "1d"},
        "assignee":        {"name": "jackburton"},
    }
```